# Accessing form controls from a different class

Tags: c#, forms

I am creating a windows form application using c#. My form has labels, list-boxes and buttons, all of which need to be edited. They are edited from a different class, and further will need the values in the labels to perform other logic.

My problem is accessing these controls from other classes. I tried making an instance of the form and using it like this:

`Form frm = new Form();
  myVar = frm.lblMylabel.Text;`

However, using a breakpoint, I followed the code, and it loops between the above instance being created, and the start of the Form code, which calls the class again where the instance was created.

I have tried to find the answer online, however they don't seem applicable to what I am trying to do, and whilst I am unsure how to do it, they appear to be overly complex. 
So, my question it: is there a relatively simple way to be able to access values and edit values from controls in a form from another class?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT - Breakpoint starts at *Point 3*, '=new Form();'.

Loops to *Point 1*.

*Point 2* calls GamePlay().

Reaches *Point 3* and loop restarts.

```
public partial class frmGame : Form     //Point 1
{
    public frmGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Game.GamePlay();    //Point 2

    }

class Game{

    public static void GamePlay()
    {
        frmGame form = new frmGame();  //Point 3

        form.lstPrevious1.Items.Add("Item Number");

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem here please.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question to include one.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with accessing properties of a different class, you are just producing a recursive loop:

At `Point 3`, within the method `GamePlay` you create a new instance of `frmGame`. When creating an instance (an object), its `constructor` is called. In this case, your constructor is the method `public frmGame()`.

Within this constructor, you now call `GamePlay` (`Point 2`), which, as we saw from before, again creates a new instance of `frmGame` (`Point 3` again), also again calling its constructor (`Point 1`).

At this point, you have already two forms created (although not shown yet).

Very soon you will receive a stack overflow.

One possible solution: Move the line creating your instance into a different method that is guaranteed to be called only once at program start:

```
public partial class frmGame : Form     //Point 1
{
    public frmGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Game.GamePlay();    //Point 2

    }
}

class Game{

    public static void GameStart(){
        frmGame form = new frmGame();  //Point 3
    }

    public static void GamePlay()
    {
        form.lstPrevious1.Items.Add("Item Number");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if i am slow on the uptake, but if I create the instance in another method, how to I ensure it is only called once? Since each time the instance is created it calls the class `frmGame`, this starts executing the code from the top of that class. However, since this class is that start of the code, the method used to create the instance will have had to be called from somewhere in `frmGame` or another method called from `frmGame`?

Comment: It can't _call_ a _class_, it only calls a _method_. In this case `Game.GamePlay`. But after your form creation is done in `Game.GameStart`, it won't get recursed again.

Comment: How would I not call the `Game.GameStart` method in the constructor?

Comment: You can do this, and by moving the object creation out of that method you don't create a loop here